# Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `className`. If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: className="false" or

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I know many people have already questioned the same question but none of their answer *worked* for me anyways...

Im having this **error**:

```
If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: className="false" or className={value.toString()}.

If you used to conditionally omit it with className={condition && value}, pass className={condition ? value : undefined} instead.
    at a
    at Link (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js:79:19)
    at li
    at SellerSidebarData (webpack-internal:///./components/sellercomp/SSData.js:17:3)
    at ul
    at div
    at div
    at SellerSidebar (webpack-internal:///./components/sellercomp/SellerSidebar.js:31:20)
    at div
    at SellerLayout (webpack-internal:///./components/sellercomp/SellerLayout.js:22:3)
    at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:55:3)
    at AppContainer (/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:27:952)
```

And this is my **code** :

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const SellerSidebarData = ({ classPath, path, icon, title }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <li>
      <Link href={path}>
        <a
          className={
            router.pathname == classPath &&
            'wave-effect waves-effect waves-button active'
          }
        >
          <i aria-hidden className={`width18 textCenter ${icon}`}></i>
          {title}
        </a>
      </Link>
    </li>
  );
};

export default SellerSidebarData;
```

Btw, i know that there is error on three files but if you could just answer the code i gave i most possibly answer the other files... Thank you so much in advance!!!

Comment: If you used to conditionally omit it with `className={condition && value}`, pass `className={condition ? value : undefined}` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are leaking a boolean to the DOM when `router.pathname == classPath` evaluates false. Use a ternary to return an empty string classname for the falsey path.

```
<Link href={path}>
  <a
    className={
      router.pathname === classPath ?
      'wave-effect waves-effect waves-button active' : ''
    }
  >
    <i aria-hidden className={`width18 textCenter ${icon}`}></i>
    {title}
  </a>
</Link>
```

Comment: im sorry for being dumb, even tho they give me an answer on the error i coudnt answer it... im just a beginner on nextjs.. THANKS!.. And Enjoy upvote and checkmark! Cheers

Comment: @xAtifx Oh, right, I didn't even scroll over to see all of the error message you'd posted. Returning `undefined` for the falsey branch is probably more *technically* correct to not return a classname at all, but returning the empty string is functionally equivalent for what you want when you don't want to provide any of your "wave-effect" and "active" classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a className={
   router.pathname == classPath ?
   'wave-effect waves-effect waves-button active':''
   }
>
```

Comment: thank you but i think you just copied the answer from the 1st guy that answered my question... anyways thanks for answering i guess

Comment: @xAtifx - the difference is that this answer uses `router.pathname == classPath` while the other answer uses `router.pathname === classPath` -- i.e. ***`==`*** not **`===`**.

Comment: ohhh sorry i checked and both works so ill give him upvote so that he wont feel bad :) thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding